# Frustrating space between hide/show button and toggle

Tags: html, css

How can i get my toggle, to toggle from the same position the hide/show button is in. instead of having a gap between the hide/show button and the toggle.

I have tried everything i can think of:

defining the margin/padding top;

putting the button within the div.

But i cannot achieve what i was hoping to achieve.

**This is how i would like it to look :**

**Before click**

[image]

**After click**

[image]

Any suggestions?

```js
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
        
                var e = document.getElementById(id);
                if (e.style.display == 'block' || e.style.display == '')
                    e.style.display = 'none';
                else
                    e.style.display = 'block';
            }
```

```css
div#first_product{
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 301px;   
}

div#red_head{
    background-color: #ed1c24;
    height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 15px;
    line-height: 35px;
}

div#first_product{
    padding:0;
    background-color: #f1f1f2;
    /*Dynamic height*/
    height:auto;
    min-height:250px;
    height:auto !important;        /* IE does not support min-height */
    height:250px;
    display: none; /*HIDE TOOGLE ON PAGE LOAD*/

}

#products_tog_but{
    background-color: #f8f9f9;
    border: 1.5px dashed #999999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}


div#hide_btn{
    width:50%;
    margin-left: 301px;
}
```

```html
        <!--HIDE TOGGLE BTN -->
        <div id="hide_btn">
            <button id="products_tog_but" onclick="toggle_visibility('first_product')">Hello!</button>
        </div>

        <!-- TOGGLE BTN SECTION-->   
        <div id="first_product">
            <div id="red_head">
                <p id="menu_title" class ="hidden" onclick="hideText('text1')" > Add your first menu item</p>
            </div>
            <h3 id="menu">Menu Section</h3>

            <form name="first_prod" id="first_prod" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="testing.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" >               

                <label id="cat_label" name="cat_label" class="lab">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="cat_name" name="cat_name" value="">
                <br>
                <label id="desc_label" name="desc_label" class="lab">Description</label>
                <input type="text" id="cat_desc" name="cat_desc" value="">

                <input type="Submit" id="save_first_prod" name="save_first_prod" onclick="toggle_visibility('first_product')" value=" + ADD"> 

            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Could you try adding margin:0; to your first_product and hide_btn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the margin-bottom of your `button` and add a `margin-top:0;` on the first `p` element

```
p#menu_title{
  margin-top:0;
}

#products_tog_but{
    background-color: #f8f9f9;
    border: 1.5px dashed #999999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/hruvayjr/2/)

Comment: hi that works. But is there any way to cover the button with the div with it toggles

Comment: I don't see exactly how it will look like, can you explain it please ?

Comment: Sorry my english is poor. I have updated the question, hopefully this can better explain what i was trying to explain

Comment: Try to add a class on the button when you click on it. On this class, you put a red background and white color and it should do the trick no ?

Comment: oh it is a simple as that. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome ! Don't forget to put this subject as solved if it's ok for you

Answer (score 0):

Remove `margin-bottom` from `#products_tog_but` and add `margin-top: -12px;` in `#first_product`

```
div#first_product{
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 301px;
    margin-top: -12px;
}

#products_tog_but{
    background-color: #f8f9f9;
    border: 1.5px dashed #999999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/jjgwpjwv/) jsfiddle for running demo.

Another way to do this instead of using margin-top as negative is:

```
p#menu_title {
  margin-top: 2px;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/jjgwpjwv/1/)